# How do I install older version of postgresql and postgis?

Tags: postgresql, postgis

I am new to Linux and I found it really difficult to install older version of postgresql (along with postgis). I have uninstalled everything I could find connected to postgresql in aptidude. As only the newest version is available through apt-get install, I have went through several tutorials how to get 9.1 installed.
Example: https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Apt (with 9.1 at the end, not 9.3)
After I was done with this tutorial, pgAdmin III is still showing 9.3 as version.
What's the correct way to dump 9.3 and install 9.1 as well as postgis 1.5?

I am using Mint 17

Comment: You'll need to give more details, since postgresql 9.1 is still available from apt.postgresql.org. Show commands and output. There's no need to uninstall old versions - you can run both on different ports.

Comment: Since you're using apt, could you doule check what dpkg tells you about the versions you have installed: `sudo dpkg --list | grep postgresql`.  This will show you what version the installed package thinks it is.

Comment: Why do you want to? Are you trying to start a base backup of an old version?

Comment: @CraigRinger Yeah, I've got db.schema from older version and I was told to launch it specifically on postgis 1.5, which requires postgresql 9.1 or older.

Comment: @couling Thanks for that command, as I said, I am fairly new and it is very useful. There are `postgresql 9.1`, `postgresql 9.3`, `postgresql-client 9.1`, `postgresql-client-common`, `postgresql-common`, `postgresql-server-dev 9.3`
so seems like I've failed tryin to uninstall 9.3. 9.1 is installed though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okay.  First off it is perfectly fine to run multiple versions of postgresql alongside one another.  You can have more than one cluster on a box, and each cluster can run different versions.  The debian pacakges are very well designed to make this easy to do.

However since you've indicated you're a newby to linux/postgresql it's probably best to get 9.3 completely cleaned from your system to avoid frustrating hiccups which will take you a long time to figure out.

To do this you need to:

1. Purge all postgresql 9.3 packages from dpkg
2. Manually delete any 9.3 data and configuration for 9.3 cluster
3. Make sure you've created a 9.1 cluster

**Step 1 – purge DPKG**

DPKG manages the packages on your system.  APT acts as a mechanism for getting packages to install.  A lot of DPKG functionality is available through apt, but some things are just easier on dpkg.  In your comments you've shown that DPKG is still showing remnants of 9.3.  When you uninstall a package some parts of it may hang around (such as configuration files).  You can remove multiple packages in one command.  To get rid of these completely you can tell dpkg to purge them `dpkg --purge <package name>`.  You can remove multiple packages in one command and it's best to do so.

`dpkg --list`  will list everything on your system.  `dpkg --list | grep postgresql` searches this list for postgresql.

**Step 2 – Manually delete data and configuration from the old 9.3 cluster.**

When you first install postgresql it creates a cluster for you; no questions asked.  This trips up a lot of new users because they neither knew that it happened nor how to replace it.  Now that 9.3 is uninstalled you can go ahead and simply delete the configuration and data:

*If there was anything you wanted to keep in the installed 9.3 database DO NOT run the following commands*

`sudo rm -rf /etc/postgresql/9.3` Removes the configuration.

`sudo rm -rf /var/lib/postgresql/9.3` Removes the data.

**Step 3 – Create a new cluster**

You've indicated in comments that postgresql 9.1 is installed.   Before you run this command it's worth reading the manual. `man pg_createcluster`.

`sudo pg_createcluster 9.1 <think up a name>`

Now you should be able to start up postgresql `sudo service postgresql start`

**Edit**

If pg_config is still listing the incorrect version then... this can be a result of remnants of 9.3 still left on your system.  This may not be a problem.  To allow multiple versions to run along side one another pg_config is a wrapper script which searches for the latest (highest version) of /usr/lib/postgresql/*/bin/pg_config.  So what you're seeing is the result of running `/usr/lib/postgresql/9.3/bin/pg_config`.  If 9.3 is completely cleaned from your system then /usr/lib/postgresql/9.3 should have gone.

If you want to see the configuration of 9.1 then try running:
`/usr/lib/postgresql/9.1/bin/pg_config`.

The wrapper scripts which starts the server will use the file structure of /etc/postgresql and use the apropriate version.  So /etc/postgresql/9.1/main will startup version as 9.1.

Comment: Thanks for detalied instructions, being such a newbie, I really appriciate that.

I've done everything as said above. I did not have to create new cluster, as `sudo apt-get install postgresql-9.1` which I used to install 9.1 (with instructions linked in main post) done in at the end, so there is cluster named `main` already runing.

One thing that is really confusing me, is that everytime I run `pg_config` it shows info about 9.3 (deleted directories, postgresql version 9.3.5 etc)

Comment: looking at dpkg, seems like  9.1 is properly installed - postgres, postgres client, postgres client common, postgres common are there. I still have problem with installing postgis though - trying to run ./configure, it still is referencing to 9.3 folder :/

Comment: I never like suggesting this as it can cause dpkg to complain later... you can delete the binaries directly by deleting the /usr/lib/postgresql/9.3 folder.  `sudo mv /usr/lib/postgresql/9.3 ~/postgresql_9.3_binaries`I'd suggest moving it for starters.

Comment: I think I found out what was the problem causing issue after your instructions. I feel bit stupid now - postgresql-server-dev-9.1 was not installed. After installation, pg_config was routing ./configuration to proper directory in 9.1 folder. ATM I have both PostgreSQL and PostGIS installed in versions I wanted. Thanks!